# How can I check whether a Unicode codepoint is assigned or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I am using Python 3 and I know all about `hex`, `int`, `chr`, `ord`, `'\uxxxx'` escape and `'\U00xxxxxx'` escape and Unicode has 1114111 codepoints...

How can I check if a Unicode codepoint is valid? That is, it is unambiguously mapped to a authoritatively defined character.

For example, codepoint 720 is valid; it is 0x2d0 in hex, and U+02D0 points to `ː`:

```py
In [135]: hex(720)
Out[135]: '0x2d0'

In [136]: '\u02d0'
Out[136]: 'ː'
```

And 888 is not valid:

```py
In [137]: hex(888)
Out[137]: '0x378'

In [138]: '\u0378'
Out[138]: '\u0378'
```

And 127744 is valid:

```py
In [139]: chr(127744)
Out[139]: ''
```

And 0xe0000 is invalid:

```py
In [140]: '\U000e0000'
Out[140]: '\U000e0000'
```

I have come up with a rather hacky solution: if a codepoint is valid, trying to convert it to a character will either result in the decoded character or the `'\xhh'` escape sequence, else it will return the undecoded escape sequence exactly same as original, I can check the return value of `chr` and check if it starts with `'\u'` or `'\U'`...

Now is the hacky part, `chr` doesn't decode invalid codepoints but it doesn't raise exceptions either, and the escape sequences will have length of 1 since they are treated as a single character, I have to `repr` the return value and check the results...

I have used this method to identify all invalid codepoints:

```py
In [130]: invalid = []

In [131]: for i in range(1114112):
     ...:     if any(f'{chr(i)!r}'.startswith(j) for j in ("'\\U", "'\\u")):
     ...:         invalid.append(i)

In [132]: from pathlib import Path

In [133]: invalid = [(hex(i).removeprefix('0x'), i) for i in invalid]

In [134]: Path('D:/invalid_unicode.txt').write_text(',\n'.join(map(repr, invalid)))
Out[134]: 18574537
```

Can anyone offer a better solution?

Comment: Side note: `chr()` doesn't do anything differently for assigned or unassigned characters. The reason they look differently is that the REPL calls `repr()` for printing return values to the command line. `repr()` distinguishes printable and non-printable characters; for example, tabs, newlines, NBSPs are consindered non-printable just like unassigned codepoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the most straight-forward approach is to use `unicodedata.category()`.
The examples from the OP are unassigned codepoints, which have a category of `Cn` ("Other, not assigned").

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.category('\u02d0')
'Lm'
>>> ud.category('\u0378')  # unassigned
'Cn'
>>> ud.category(chr(127744))
'So'
>>> ud.category('\U000e0000')  # unassigned
'Cn'
```

It also works for the control characters in the ASCII range:

```
>>> ud.category('\x00')
'Cc'
```

Further categories for invalid codepoints (according to comments) are `Cs` ("Other, surrogate") and `Co` ("Other, private use"):

```
>>> ud.category('\ud800')  # lower surrogate
'Cs'
>>> ud.category('\uf8ff')  # private use
'Co'
```

So a function for codepoint validity (as per the OP's definition) could look like this:

```py
def is_valid(char):
    return ud.category(char) not in ('Cn', 'Cs', 'Co')
```

**Important caveat:** Python's `unicodedata` module embeds a certain version of Unicode, so the information is potentially out of date.
For example, in my installation of Python 3.8, the Unicode version is 12.1.0, so it doesn't know about codepoints assigned in later versions of Unicode:

```
>>> ud.unidata_version
'12.1.0'
>>> ud.category('\U0001fae0')  # melting face emoji added in Unicode v14
'Cn'
```

If you need a more recent version of Unicode than the one of your Python version, you probably need to fetch an appropriate table directly from Unicode.

Comment: If you are working directly with JSON strings, then `Cs` codepoints would be valid characters. `Co` characters would also be valid characters, there are lots of reasons to use PUA characters including scripts not yet encoded in Unicode, as a trasitional mechanism. Likewise there are a few registries for PUA assignments including CSUR, MUFI, SIL, TITUS. GB/T 20542-2006, GB/T 22238-2008, GB 18030, and GBK make use of PUA. Historically Apple, Microsoft and Adobe used PUA assignments and can still be found in old documents.

Comment: `Cn` is a bit more problematic, its made up of two classes of characters: 1) noncharacters, and 2) reserved characters. There are 64 noncharacters defined in Unicode, and there can be valid uses for these, so they aren't by default considered invalid characters. Which leaves a subset of `Cn` characters as invalid, i.e. unassigned (reserved) codeponts.

Comment: @Andj thanks for the knowledgable additions. In my experience one always faces the same trade-off when trying to divide [Unicode] characters into sensible groups: an elegant/simple, but very approximate solution vs. a tailor-made one with your own rules or tables. If the former isn't good enough, you end up with the latter, which is a pain to maintain.

Comment: part of the problem is that Python's Unicode support is fairly primitive. As you indicate, trying to create sets of characters can be challenging. More often I have been resorting to PyICU and building Unicode Sets. If i wanted unassigned characters, i'd use the set `[\p{Cn}]` or `[\p{Unassigned}]`. If I wanted the set of reserved characters, I'd use `[[\p{Unassigned}]-[\p{Noncharacter_Code_Point}]]`, and use those sets to create a list of target codepoints. The core problem is lack of documentation on the Python side, and a mydraid of documents to explore on the Unicode side.

Comment: Something like `reserved = list(icu.UnicodeSet(r'[[\p{Unassigned}]-[\p{Noncharacter_Code_Point}]]'))` then a condition like `char not in reserved`, etc.

Comment: or maybe use `[^[[\p{Unassigned}]-[\p{Noncharacter_Code_Point}]]]` which would create a smaller list, since there are less non-reserved characters than reserved characters. So the coomplement of the set difference between Unassigned and Noncharacter codepoints.

Comment: @Andj sounds like you should summarise this all in a decent answer of your own rather than hiding this in the comments :)

Comment: maybe I should ... but few are interested in the ins and outs of Unicode in Python. For Python devs, usually "close enough is good enough".

Answer (score 0):

I think [`unicodedata.name()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.name) sort of does what you want.

Comment: One caveat though, all first 256 codepoints are valid, but the library doesn't report names of c0 and c1 control characters... I have to make a `range(256)` check first...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the [unicode-charnames](https://pypi.org/project/unicode-charnames/) library, independent from the Python core Unicode database. This package supports version 14.0 of the Unicode Standard (released September 14, 2021).

```
from unicode_charnames import charname, UNICODE_VERSION

assigned = []
control = []
private_use = []
surrogate = []
noncharacter = []
reserved = []
for x in range(0x110000):
    name = charname(chr(x))
    if not name.startswith("<"):  # code points assigned to an abstract character
        assigned.append(x)
    elif name.startswith("<control"):
        control.append(x)
    elif name.startswith("<private"):
        private_use.append(x)
    elif name.startswith("<surrogate"):
        surrogate.append(x)
    elif name.startswith("<noncharacter"):
        noncharacter.append(x)
    else:
        reserved.append(x)

print(f"# Unicode {UNICODE_VERSION}")
print(f"Code points assigned to an abstract character: {len(assigned):,}")
print(f"Unassigned code points: {len(reserved):,}")
print( "Code points with a normative function:")
print(f"   Control characters     -> {len(control):>7,}")
print(f"   Private-use characters -> {len(private_use):>7,}")
print(f"   Surrogate characters   -> {len(surrogate):>7,}")
print(f"   Noncharacters          -> {len(noncharacter):>7,}")
```

Output:

```
# Unicode 14.0.0
Code points assigned to an abstract character: 144,697
Unassigned code points: 829,768
Code points with a normative function:
   Control characters     ->      65
   Private-use characters -> 137,468
   Surrogate characters   ->   2,048
   Noncharacters          ->      66
```

The file you need is **DerivedName.txt**, available in the Unicode Character Database (UCD). The file for version 14.0 can be found [here](https://www.unicode.org/Public/14.0.0/ucd/extracted/DerivedName.txt).

Answer (score 0):

The OP's title refers to whether a codepoint is an *unassigned codepoint* or not, while the body of the question refers to the validity of a codepoint, and "whether it is unambiguously mapped to a authoritatively defined character".

The term *valid* usually is used regarding sequences, either in terms of valid encoding sequences, i.e UTF_8, UTF-16 or UTF-32 sequences, or in terms of valid character sequences, usually used in terms of valid ligatures, emoji sequences, variation selectors, etc. So the notion of **valid** isn't exactly what the question is about.

Unicode also has the notion of **Unassigned Characters** and **Unassigned Codepoints**.

### Unassigned Characters

An *Unassigned Character* is codepoint not assigned to an abstract character. This includes surrogate code points, noncharacters, and reserved code points.

This covers the general categories *Other, surrogate (Cs)* and
*Other, not assigned (Cn)*. The approach in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69780841/4872676) can be used for *Unassigned Characters*.

### Unassigned Codepoints

An *Unassigned Codepoint* is an alias for a *Reserved Codepoint*, which is a codepoint reserved for allocation in a future version of the Unicode standard, i.e. it isn't used now, but may be used in the future.

The general category *Other, not assigned (Cn)* contains both reserved codepoints and noncharacters. Noncharacters are codepoints that are permanently reserved for internal use. So *Other, not assigned (Cn)* contains more than just reserved codepoints.

### Using PyICU to untangle things

PyICU is a wrapper around ICU4C, and supports Unicode sets. I'll use Unicode sets to target the required characters.

We have three ways of defining a valid codepoint:

1. a valid codepoint is any non-reserved codepoint
2. a valid codepoint is any assigned codepoint
3. a valid codepoint is any codepoint that is neither unassigned nor a surrogate codepoint, i.e. an assigned character.

#### Non-reserved codepoints

We create a complement of the set difference between the set of unassigned characters and the set of noncharacters. Using Perl notation, unassigned characters can be specified by `\p{Cn}` or `\p{Unassigned}`, and noncharacters can be specified by  `\p{Noncharacter_Code_Point}`.

```py
import icu
non_reserved = list(icu.UnicodeSet(r'[^[[\p{Unassigned}]-[\p{Noncharacter_Code_Point}]]]'))
def is_valid(char):
    return True if char in non_reserved else False

is_valid('\u02d0')  # assigned codepoint
# True
is_valid('\u0378')  # reserved codepoint
# False
is_valid('\ufddf')   # noncharacter
# True
is_valid('\ud800')    # surrogate codepoint
# True
```

#### Assigned codepoints

The second way to determine validity is to check if a codepoint is an assigned codepoint:

```py
assigned = list(icu.UnicodeSet(r'[\P{Unassigned}]'))
def is_valid(char):
    return True if char in assigned else False

is_valid('\u02d0')  # assigned codepoint
# True
is_valid('\u0378')  # reserved codepoint
# False
is_valid('\ufddf')   # noncharacter
# False
is_valid('\ud800')    # surrogate codepoint
# True
```

#### Assigned characters

The third way to define a validity is based on whether a codepoint belongs to an assigned character:

```py
assigned_char = list(icu.UnicodeSet(r'[^[[\p{Unassigned}][\p{Surrogate}]]]'))
def is_valid(char):
    return True if char in assigned_char else False

is_valid('\u02d0')  # assigned codepoint
# True
is_valid('\u0378')  # reserved codepoint
# False
is_valid('\ufddf')   # noncharacter
# False
is_valid('\ud800')    # surrogate codepoint
# False
```

Alternatively, it is possible to use *unicodedata* module for this definition, although I prefer to use the *unicodedataplus* module instead:

```bash
pip install -U unicodedataplus
```

*unicodedataplus* is updated with each release of a new Unicode version. Adapting the code from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69780841/4872676):

```py
import unicodedataplus as ud
def is_valid(char):
    return True if ud.category(char) not in ('Cn', 'Cs') else False

is_valid('\u02d0')  # assigned codepoint
# True
is_valid('\u0378')  # reserved codepoint
# False
is_valid('\ufddf')   # noncharacter
# False
is_valid('\ud800')    # surrogate codepoint
# False
```

### Notes

Some answers include Private Use Codepoints (Co). PUA codepoints aren't included in the definition of either unassigned characters or unassigned characters.

There are reasons to use PUA characters. One scenario involves scripts not yet encoded in Unicode, as a transitional mechanism.

Likewise, there are a few registries for PUA codepoint assignments including CSUR, MUFI, SIL, TITUS. The GB/T 20542-2006, GB/T 22238-2008, GB 18030, and GBK encoding standards make use of PUA codepoints. Historically Apple, Microsoft and Adobe used PUA assignments and can still be found in old documents.

There are times when you may find surrogate pairs in your data. At times I have to work with JSON and JSON-LD data, including processing it and converting it to other formats. It is necessary to read it as a JSON string, rather than converting it to a python object.

Characters in the SMP, SIP and TIP planes, including most emoji, where escaped, are represented in JSON as escaped surrogate pairs, and will exist in a JSON string in Python as surrogate pairs:

```py
import json
data = {"Adlm": " "}
data_json = json.dumps(data)
print(data_json)
# {"Adlm": "\ud83a\udd00\ud83a\udd23\ud83a\udd24\ud83a\udd22\ud83a\udd25 \ud83a\udd06\ud83a\udd35\ud83a\udd24\ud83a\udd22\ud83a\udd2a"}
```